# NUnit consistency across multiple environments via SVN

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010, deployment, nunit

We have multiple contributors working on a C# project in Visual Studio 2010. I'd like to use NUnit, but ensure that the proper version of it is included in our repository. I know it can be done, I just can't find a good reference on it.

I think it has to do with including the right .dll files in the solution and referencing the assembly that way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not aware about online guidelines for this (if any), but to my understanding the procedure will be quite similar to the same one for any framework which is added to the sources instead of being referenced from outside.

So, I would do the following:

- Find out which projects of your solution use NUnit. For instance, uninstall NUnit and try to build your application
- For each failed project find out what DLLs of NUnit are referenced from it
- Add NUnit binaries (only those which are referenced by your projects) to the source control
- Reference those added binaries from your projects instead of referencing those installed by official NUnit build
- Try to build the solution again

This can be an iterative process. For instance, if NUnit binaries you use reference others, it will complain about broken reference. Add such extra libraries one by one until the build is successful. Make sure the official NUnit is uninstalled when you try this in order to be confident all references are local.

Hope this helps.